# How to Fix: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: ‘str’ and ‘str’

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror, operands

I am new to python. I am trying to do some operation with my data set

I am trying to do this operation

```
matches['rank_difference'] = matches['rank_home'] - matches['rank_away']
matches['average_rank'] = (matches['rank_home'] + matches['rank_away'])/2
```

whenever i run this program i get this

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Even i tried to convert the variable to numeric but its not converting a it remains in serious

If I tried like this

```
matches['rank_difference'] = int(matches['rank_home']) -int( matches['rank_away'])
```

The error is

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

how to reslove this error

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- this includes a small, representative sample of your dataset, and your expected outcome.

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: The error means that `rank_home` and `rank_away` contain strings, not numbers. You should fix the dtype of the columns.